# Polyline Colour doesn't change

Tags: java, android, api, maps, polyline

The polyline colour doesn't change even after doing this:

```
Polyline p;
lineOptions=new PolylineOptions();
lineOptions.addAll(points);
lineOptions.width(12);
lineOptions.geodesic(true);
lineOptions.clickable(true);
lineOptions.color(Color.BLACK);
p = mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
```

My question is why?

Points is a previously declared LatLng ArrayList.

Comment: What color is the polyline currently showing?

Comment: The polyline is black, there's no change.

Comment: Why are you setting the color twice? `lineOptions.color(Color.BLACK);`  and `p.setColor(Color.BLUE);` or is it just theoretical.

Comment: I did it just to see the working.

Comment: Polylines don't work like that... you set polyline color before it is drawn on map not aferwards

Comment: And what if you want to change the colour of the one which is already drawn?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color of polyline which is already drawn on the map,then you need to add that polyline (of updated color) to the map, to notify that we have changed the color as below:

```
lineOptions.color(Color.BLACK);
p = mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
if(p !=null) {
    p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    mMap.addPolyline(p);
}
```

It will change the color from black to blue

Hope this helps!